# Rails: ensure capitalization in model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, input, capitalization

In a Rails model, if I have a field that is for proper names, what is the best practice way to ensure they are uniformly capitalized despite potentially lazy input from users?

IE let's say the model is `Contact` and the field is `Name`. No matter what the user inputs I want the words to be capitalized, ie the model would tranform the following input to the following output:

```
john doe -> John Doe
j doe -> J Doe
John doe -> John Doe
john doe jr -> John Doe Jr
```

So, do you create a `before_save` callback and tranform the field with a regex, or do you create some kind of validation, or something different? I'd very much appreciate answers with an emphasis on the rationale, of *why* you would do it one way or another, because that's what I'm most stuck on.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The method you want is `titleize`. The `capitalize` method only does the first character in the entire string so `"john doe".capitalize #=> "John doe"`, `"john doe".titleize #=> "John Doe"`.

As for how to implement it, you could go with a `before_save`, but I like to do these type of simple preparations of single attributes with pseudo-attributes. Basically, you define a `writer` method for an attribute that will hide the default one created by `ActiveRecord`. You'll still be able to access the attribute using the `write_attribute` method ([docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Write.html#method-i-write_attribute)). Doing it this way will ensure that the attribute is set properly **as soon as you assign it**, meaning that even before you save it, you can be sure your object is in a valid state:

```rb
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base

  def name=(s)
    write_attribute(:name, s.to_s.titleize) # The to_s is in case you get nil/non-string
  end

end
```

Comment: I love it! I wasn't familiar with `write_attribute` but, wow, what a useful technique! This solves the problem perfectly three lines of code, and all specs passed on first try.  One little thing, in your code example `self` is actually not required, I fixed it for you.

Comment: @Andrew Oh, right. I forgot that `write_attribute` is `private`. It's weird that its sister method `read_attribute` is public though. Anyway, glad you liked the tip. Happy coding!

Answer (score 8):

A cleaner rendition of @tserif's is the following:

```
def name=(s)
    super s.titleize
end
```

This removes the dependency on `write_attribute` and the need to specify the attribute name `name` in favor of a more primitive method. I don't see the need for `to_s`, unless you want the ability to assign a symbol.

Comment: def name=(s)
    super s&.titleize
  end

Comment: .to_s protects against nils.  eg.
`irb(main):123:0> nil.titleize
NoMethodError: undefined method 'titleize' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to use before_save .

like in you model :

```
before_save :capitalize_name

def capitalize_name
  self.name = self.name.split.collect(&:capitalize).join(' ') if self.name && !self.name.blank?
end
```

Answer (score 3):

The most important question is how will you be displaying the names? If it will be on the web, as I would guess, I wouldn't handle this in the model at all. The simplest solution is to just use css `text-tansform: capitalize;` to handle the capitalization, but if you'll be displaying it often you would want to define a decorator or helper method to normalize it for you.

```
def full_name
  [first_name, last_name].map { |name| name[0].upcase + name[1..-1] }.join(' ')
end
```

Note that instead of mapping `capitalize` you would just want to uppercase the first letter. Somebody named RJ or CJ would probably want the J to remain capitalized.

The data is canonical regardless, seeing the parts capitalized is purely display.